# Fetch data having a specific id defined in the view instance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to `fetch` data having a specific id
and which id is defined in the view instance.
Here the example, see the comments in MyModel definition:

```
// my view instance
var myView = new MyView({
    model: {id: 12321}
});
```

---

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extends({
        initialize: function()
        { 
            myModel.fetch();
        }
});
```

---

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
        url: function url ()  
        {
          // how to get the id passed to view instance?
          return "http:..../id/" + this.id; 
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model should not has any knowledge of the existence of the View, so the View should be the one that sais to the Model which `id` to fetch:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extends({
        initialize: function()
        { 
            myModel.id = this.model.id;
            myModel.fetch();
        }
});
```

*(I've used your example code as template for my example, but I have to say I feel several weird things on it, I suppose is just a matter of taste)*

### Update: My very personal taste opinions

Is very difficult to do this but as you requested I'll share with you my very personal code review of your example code. Take this as it is: a very humble opinion.

#### this.model confused

I would not use attribute names that can create confussion:

```
var myView = new MyView({
    model: {id: 12321}
});
```

Into this instance `this.model` is making reference to a *raw* Hash but in a Backbone context this is against the intuitive feeling that this is gonna be a *Backbone.Model*.

I rather change it for something like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ){
     this.model_id = opts.model_id;
  }
})
var myView = new MyView({ model_id: 12321 });
```

I think this *naming* is more intuitive.

#### close variables scopes

This code can only works if `myModel` is in an scope bigger that it should be:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extends({
        initialize: function()
        { 
            myModel.fetch();
        }
});
```

I rather prefer using more encapsulated scopes, even if `myModel` has been declared in the out-side context of your View the View should use a variable of its private context. For example

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extends({
  initialize: function( opts ) { 
    this.model = opts.model;
    this.model.fetch();
  }
});

var myView = new MyView({ model: myModel });
```

Check the detail that I have also added `var` in front of `MyView` because if not `MyView` will be a `window` global variable.

#### use the Backbone urlRoot

In your example, this ...

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
    url: function url ()  
    {
      // how to get the id passed to view instance?
      return "http:..../id/" + this.id; 
    }
});
```

... can be summarized as this:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
    urlRoot: "http:..../id"
});
```

Comment: thanks for your sincerity. Can you tell me what do you disagree or how would you implement the things?

Comment: I have added explanation after your request